# How can I have both right-aligned and left-aligned text in a list item such as in the provided picture?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I need to write sequences of ordered statements along with their justifications and for that I have to write lists with both left-aligned and right-aligned text. This is my starting point:

```
\begin{enumerate}
        \item for all \(x, y\) s.t. \(|x| < |y|:x^2<y^2\)
        \item \(|a| < |b|\)
        \item{ \(a^2 < b^2\) (1,2; us \forall)}
\end{enumerate}
```

And it should look like this:

[image: list with 3 items, third item has both left-aligned and right-aligned text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a \hfill to the last item, something like:

```
\item{ \(a^2 < b^2\)\hfill(1,2; us $\forall$)}
```

should do what you ask (right-aligning the '(1,2; us \forall)' bit). 
If you want to keep some space after the text, you can use \hspace* (the starred version prevents LaTeX removing the space at the end of a line)

Comment: @user151387 then please consider pressing the 'accept answer' button.